# Is there a way to limit VPN resources on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I have corporate VPN profile at home PC I use to work.
Is there a way to limit its profile area so I can interact with work resources by VPN, but any other resources I'd interact with the default Windows net settings?

It works by IKEv2 and profiled inside built-in Windows Network settings as separate VPN service.

It's used to connect to corporate web resources through the browser and access to separate virtual machines using terminal.

Comment: This is called "split tunneling". Without more details about the VPN type, client software, involved subnets and possibly DNS, an answer isn't possible.

Comment: IKEv2, built-in Windows VPN profiler. Have no nothing about subnets and DNS, only server address

Comment: Make sure to add all additional information directly to your question. // If you do not know any details, please at least describe how you access remote resources, like “with the browser, go to _jira.mycorp.com_” or something like that.

Comment: Not a duplicate because this is about the Windows built-in IKEv2 client.

Comment: @DanielB I added that specs to the question.

Comment: Those are not enough details, sorry. I may have worded it imprecisely. It is _critical_ that we know whether you connect to host names or IP addresses. This is so we can guide you in adding the split tunneling rules.

Comment: Oh yeah, and if it's host names, it's also relevant whether they all have the same ending (or few endings) or if they're all over the place, and lots of 'em.

Comment: @DanielB It is hostname. It's constant like pre.hostname.com, used by user credentials.